# iAd is not popping up anymore since iOS 9 update

Tags: ios, objective-c, iad

I have an App in the App Store, its called "Sanchez and the Aliens".

The iAd banner was working on the phones, but now, a friend told me he updated his iPhone to iOS 9 and  now he can't see any more ads. I tested it a few more times, and whenever i update to iOS 9, the iAd Banner doesn't pop up anymore.

Does anybody know an answer so far?

Thanks for any help regarding my problem!

Comment: Are you sure that the iAd network is just not down at the moment? iAd advertisements are working on my applications running on iOS 9.

Comment: Were you able to get around this problem?